# two grid view not rendered properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatables

i have one page that have two grid view. one get binds up and renders with datatable properly. how ever another grid view no renders like him.

here is my grid view codes:
First Gird View:

```
protected void egrd_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (egrd.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            egrd.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            egrd.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        }
    }
```

Result 1:
[image]
Sencond Grid View :

```
 protected void gvSubscribers_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvSubscribers.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvSubscribers.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gvSubscribers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        }
    }
```

Result 2:

[image]

what's going wrong here is there jquery datatable pulgin not works with two grid view on one single page.

**--------------------------------Updated------------------------------------**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
                $('[id$=egrd]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($('[id$=egrd]').find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
                    "responsive": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "stateDuration": 60 * 1
                });
                $('[id$=gvSubscribers]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($('[id$=gvSubscribers]').find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
                    "responsive": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "stateDuration": 60 * 1
                });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: show us the javascript code

Comment: well i use this code for google article and works little charm!!